# SNAIVE METHOD getting same result for different estimators (BU, OLS and STRUC) on THIEF package in R (TSAGGREGATES + RECONCILETHIEF)

Tags: r, forecasting, accuracy, frequency, aggregation

I'm stucked and don't know how to solve that **problem using thief package in R** (actually tsaggragates + reconcile thief) for **SNAIVE METHOD**. Does anyone can check it and see what is wrong with it? If it's not wrong, what are the possible outcomes or answers for that?

I have an example of time series using train-test approach. As you can check on code below, I separate than in "b" and "c" series. As exampled on [reconcilethief documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/thief/versions/0.3/topics/reconcilethief), I made different frequencies for each one using tsaggregates() and after, I calculated for each frequency it's SNAIVE forecast.

As mentioned on [the article "Forecasting with Temporal Hierarchy"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221717301911), father of THIEF (Am I wrong?), I **want to compare the results from estimators: BU, OLS and WS**.

The Problem is: When I compare those results on each frequency, **they all look the same ONLY for SNAIVE method**. For NAIVE, ETS, ARIMA and THETA it works pretty well and get different results.

**Am I doing something wrong? What is the possibles outcomes or answers for that result?**

PS: I'm not worried if it fits well that data because it is just an example. It is just a practical way to address my problem/difficulties.

```
#install.packages("forecast")
#install.packages("thief")

library(forecast); library(thief)

#Data
b <- c(1237,1982,1191,1163,1418,1687,2331,2181,1943,1782,177,1871,391,1397,734,712,1006,508,368,767,675,701,989,725,1292,983,1094,1105,928,1246,1604,1163,1390,959,1630,789,1173,910,875,718,655,606,968,716,476,476,655,499,544,1250,359,386,458,947,542,953,1450,1195,1317,957,778,1030,1399,1119,3142,1024,1537,1321,2062,1897,2094,2546,1796,2089,1194,896,727,599,785,674,828,311,375,315,365,314,126,315,372,666,596,589,001,613,498,635,644,1018,873,900,502,121,293,259,311,169,378,153,24,115,250,565,349,201,393,83,327,325,185,307,501,194)
b <- ts(b, start = 1949, frequency = 12)
c <- window(b, start = 1949, end = c(1954,12), frequency = 12)

#Aggregated time series (total and training session)
aggserie = tsaggregates(b)
aggts = tsaggregates(c)
fcs = list()

# Calculating snaives methods for each frequency
for(i in seq_along(aggts)){
  fcs[[i]] = snaive(aggts[[i]], h= freq*frequency(aggts[[i]]))}

# Results for different variance estimator
rt_bu = reconcilethief(fcs, comb = c("bu")); 
rt_ols = reconcilethief(fcs, comb = c("ols")); 
rt_struc = reconcilethief(fcs, comb = c("struc")); 

#Plot for each frequency comparing each estimator (BU, OLS and WS)
par(mfrow=c(2,3), bg = NA); for(i in seq_along(fcs)){
  plot(aggserie[[i]], main=names(aggserie)[i], ylab = "Qty", xlab = "Time"); 
  lines(fcs[[i]]$mean, col='red', type ="b"); 
  lines(rt_struc[[i]]$mean, col = "blue", type = "l"); 
  lines(rt_bu[[i]]$mean, col = "green", type = "l");
  lines(rt_ols[[i]]$mean, col = "brown", type = "l");
}
```

The image shows the result for each estimator on each frequency.
[image: Result for each frequency comparing BU, OLS and WS estimators]

And here are the accuracy measurements for 2-monthly frequency (Just change number 2 for another from 1 to 6 to check other frequencies results):

```
accuracy(rt_struc[[2]],aggserie[[2]])
accuracy(rt_bu[[2]],aggserie[[2]])
accuracy(rt_ols[[2]],aggserie[[2]])

#> accuracy(rt_struc[[2]],aggserie[[2]])
#                      ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set    32.86667 1398.514 1151.000  -23.67196  64.23187 1.000000 0.7046529        NA
#Test set     -2018.25000 2577.705 2364.417 -252.60259 261.51293 2.054228 0.1678267   5.97304
#> accuracy(rt_bu[[2]],aggserie[[2]])
#                      ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set    32.86667 1398.514 1151.000  -23.67196  64.23187 1.000000 0.7046529        NA
#Test set     -2018.25000 2577.705 2364.417 -252.60259 261.51293 2.054228 0.1678267   5.97304
#> accuracy(rt_ols[[2]],aggserie[[2]])
#                      ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set    32.86667 1398.514 1151.000  -23.67196  64.23187 1.000000 0.7046529        NA
#Test set     -2018.25000 2577.705 2364.417 -252.60259 261.51293 2.054228 0.1678267   5.97304
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seasonal naive method uses the most recent year of data as the forecast. So the forecasts are already coherent because the data are coherent. Hence, any reconciliation approach using `snaive` will give the same results.